# How to get the algebraic expression for $y = r(-2x) + 3$, given function $r$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

So it says the parent function is $r(x) =1/x$. Then the new function in terms of $r(x)=1/x$ is $y=r(-2x)+3$.

I'm not sure how to get the algebraic expression. I came up with $y=(-1/2x)+3$ Was that the right answer?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your answer is right.

Specifically, you realized that $r(-2x) = \frac{1}{(-2x)} = -\frac{1}{2x}$. So then $y = - \frac{1}{2x} + 3$.

Comment: For describing the transformation, would you say it's a reflection on the y axis, stretch by a factor of 2, and shift up 3 units?

Comment: @Hamze Yes, but instead of "stretch by a factor of 2" it's "squish by a factor of 2, horizontally".